# Add polygon of n sides using \pgfmathsetmarco

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf, polygon

Hello i have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[help lines, color=gray!30] (0,0) grid (12,12);
\draw[->] (1,6)--(11,6);
\draw[->] (6,1)--(6,11);

\draw (6,6) circle [radius=4cm];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which outputs:

[image]

My question is how can I add a polygon of N sides (which corners lie on the circle) to this picture using the \pgfmathsetmacro command to set a value for N (so the number of sides of the polygon should be easily changeable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Here's one way to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[help lines, color=gray!30] (0,0) grid (12,12);
        \draw[->] (1,6)--(11,6);
        \draw[->] (6,1)--(6,11);
        
        \draw (6,6) circle [radius=4cm];
        
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{5}
        \foreach \i in {0, ..., \n} {
            \draw ($(\i*360/\n:4) + (6, 6)$) -- ($(\i*360/\n+360/\n:4) + (6, 6)$);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This works by moving around the circle drawing straight line segments at the correct angles for them to form the required polygon.

Answer (score 4):

With `shapes.geometric` library, you can declare regular polygons with any number of sides. If you declare them with certain `minimum size`, this size is the diameter of corresponding circumcircle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[help lines, color=gray!30] (0,0) grid (12,12);
\draw[->] (1,6)--(11,6);
\draw[->] (6,1)--(6,11);

\draw (6,6) circle [radius=4cm];
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=7, minimum size=8cm, draw=red, shape border rotate=30] at (6,6) {};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4, minimum size=8cm, draw=blue, shape border rotate=45] at (6,6) {};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5, minimum size=8cm, draw=green, shape border rotate=25] at (6,6) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]